# Make a toolbar that is part of a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have been implementing a `UIPageViewController` and would like to add a toolbar to the bottom of my `UIPageViewController` that contains 3 buttons. Sadly, I can't figure out how to do this as I can only put the toolbar on one of the `UIViewController`and when I transition to another view controller the toolbar is no longer there. Is it possible to create a toolbar that spans all `UIViewController`'s that are embedded in the `UIPageViewController`?
Thanks in advance.

edit: I have already implemented my UIPageViewController and have added two UIViewControllers inside the UIPageViewController. Is it still possible? Maybe it is possible to embed my already created `UIPageViewController` in a `UIVIewController`?

Comment: Add toolbar to UIViewController that are added as child view controllers to UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create UIViewController and add `UIPageViewController` in that. Add that toolbar on `UIViewController`. after adding `UIPageviewcontroller` bring subview to front that toolbar.

So your view hierarchy will be `UIViewController` > `UIPageviewcontroller` > `Toolbar`.

As your toolbar is added on UIViewController it will be shown above all pageviewcontroller's viewcontroller.